# Recursive rectangle sub division

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm really curious about this image and I have little to no information how it was created. Thus, I'm here to research how to do it.

Can someone tell me where to begin? I only know this problem might be related to a **recursive subdivision** task.

I can only see the images was divided into 64 blocks initially.
There is some color simplification going on which I don't understand how to achieve this and am curious about how to do it.
A reference to an algorithm or procedure is enough(python/c++ only please)

[image]

Comment: looks like fibonacci sequence is applied to some parts the photo divided into a grid

Comment: yes, it does look like golden ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of Google Images I was able to find the name of the person who is in the image: Kenny Cason. With some more research I was able to find the answer.

The problem is related to **Quad Tree Images**:

1. Partition the image into four quadrants.
2. Color each quadrant based on the average color of the pixels in the
   target image.
3. Compute each quadrant's squared error between the original target
   image and the generated image.
4. Select the quadrant with the highest error and recur into it.
5. Repeat from step one, using the current highest error quadrant.

GitHub [link](https://github.com/kennycason/art).

Kenny Cason's [blog](https://kennycason.com/posts/2018-10-01-quad-tree-images.html) .

Comment: Note that the squared error is equal to the variance, because you're comparing to the mean value.

Answer (score 2):

You could have squares of the average color of that part of the image, check how similar it is to the original using something like [image similarity measures](https://pypi.org/project/image-similarity-measures/) and if its not good enough, subdivide into 4 squares and make them each the average color of that part of the image. Repeat this until every square in the image is good enough.

Comment: Typically these things use the variance within the square as a measure for whether to further divide it or not.